# How to run Nodejs Embedded Library on multiple threads

Tags: c++, node.js

I am writing a wrapper DLL around libnode.dll and seem to need to call `node::SpinEventLoop(env)` every time there is an asynchronous method inside the Nodejs script.

The question I have is is this necessary? And if it is, how to I enter the Nodejs runtime from another C++ application thread, as `node::SpinEventLoop(env)` seems to require `v8::Locker` which locks the v8 runtime, preventing any access to the isolate, to for example do a `v8::Object::Get` on a `v8::Value`?

I am currently allowing `SpinEventLoop` in the following way:

```cpp
void spinEventLoop() {
  v8::Locker locker(isolate);
  printf("locked isolate, spinning event loop\n");
  node::SpinEventLoop(env).FromMaybe(1);
  printf("unlocking isolate, finished spinning event loop\n");
}

EXTERN void MyLib_SpinEventLoop() {
  std::thread t(spinEventLoop);
  t.detach();
}
```

I've tried to keep the Isolate alive by adding `setInterval(() => {}, 60000)` inside the JS code, and I don't particularly want to have to manage `SpinEventLoop` calls from the application, forcing them to guess when the isolate is running or not. If I have to, do you have any recommendations for how to do this?

Just by way of explanation. The asynchronous methods are being run in a v8 MicroTask, perhaps this is the issue, and I need to do a PerformMicrotaskCheckpoint each time I run the tasks?

Answer (score -1):

I managed to fix this by manually running the libuv event loop with `UV_RUN_NOWAIT` and then waiting the designated period of time between runs.

A shame there doesn't seem to be a way to wait for a `uv_run` that actually does something.

```cpp
void spinEventLoop() {
  while(true) {
      v8::Locker locker(isolate);
      v8::Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);
      v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);
      v8::Context::Scope context_scope(context->Get(isolate));
      eventLoop = node::GetCurrentEventLoop(isolate);
      uv_run(eventLoop, UV_RUN_NOWAIT);
      {
        isolate->Exit();
        v8::Unlocker unlocker(isolate);
        int timeout = uv_backend_timeout(eventLoop);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::duration<int, std::nano>(timeout));
      }
      isolate->Enter();
  }
}
```

Is this the right way to go about this?